# MemoryStream(Xls) to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memorystream, flexcel

I'm using the library FlexCel and need to convert a `MemoryStream` (Xls Type) to PDF. I tried this form but not work.

```
oFlexCelReport.Run(oTemplateMemoryStream, oOutMemoryStream);
oOutMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
using (FlexCelPdfExport pdf = new FlexCelPdfExport(oXlsFile, true))
{
    pdf.Export(oOutMemoryStream);
}
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? what error do you receive? On which line in particular? Please provide more info so that people can better help you. This might be of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It does not contain error, the file is only empty.